# Cross product of the reals question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\Bbb {R} \times \Bbb {R} \subseteq \Bbb {R}$?

If this is the case then would it be true that $|\Bbb {R} \times \Bbb {R}| \leq |\Bbb {R}|$?

Comment: Doesn't the cross product on the LHS have two components while the RHS has one? How can it be a subset?

Comment: Could you explain *why* you think that the first inclusion is true?  I am wondering if you might be confusing "cartesian product" with "multiplication".

Comment: I mean the cross product.  I'm trying to eventually prove that $\Bbb {R} \times \Bbb {R} \sim \Bbb {R}$.  So I'm trying to prove that $|\Bbb {R} \times \Bbb {R}| \leq |\Bbb {R}|$.  And I know that if $S \subseteq T$, then $|S| \leq |T|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb R \times  \mathbb R \subseteq \mathbb R$ is incorrect.

It is incorrect for the same reason that in vector spaces $\mathbb R^3 \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is incorrect. The number of components is different.

However...

The statement $|\mathbb R \times  \mathbb R| \leq |\mathbb R|$ is correct. and infact, it is true that $|\mathbb R \times  \mathbb R| = |\mathbb R|$

A simple proof for $|\mathbb R \times  \mathbb R| \leq |\mathbb R|$ without resorting to cardinal arithmetique would be to find a function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ that is injective. Can you think of such function? how about $f(i,j)=2^i3^j$?

Comment: This function is ***really*** not injective in the case of $\Bbb R$. Take $(1,1)$ and $(\log_2(3),\log_3(2))$ are an easy counterexample.

Comment: In my haste I thought about $\mathbb N$...Regardless, it is possible to think of such a function

Comment: Of course, it's possible to think about it. But you will ultimately end up doing work roughly as hard as proving that $\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ have the same cardinality. And cardinal arithmetics gives you, in that case, an incredibly general and easy solution.

Answer (score 4):

The elements of $\Bbb{R\times R}$ are ordered pairs of real numbers. The elements of $\Bbb R$ are real numbers. Under the "usual" interpretation in mathematics, real numbers are not ordered pairs of real numbers. Therefore $\Bbb{R\cap (R\times R)=\varnothing}$.

In either case, it is true that $\Bbb{|R|=|R\times R|}$ as follows almost immediately from the fact that $|\Bbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}$, and simple cardinal arithmetics.